Unperturbed Green's Function for an electron in an empty band
I'm going through Mahan's many body physics, and he shows that for an electron in an empty band the unperturbed Green's function is given by
$$G^{(0)}(\lambda,t-t')=-i\Theta(t-t')e^{-i\epsilon_\lambda(t-t')}$$
He then takes the Fourier transform of this, but there are two things I'm not so sure about

He introduces an infinitesimal quantity $i\delta$ to the exponent to ensure the integral
$$G^{(0)}(\lambda,E)=-i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i(E-\epsilon_\lambda+i\delta)t}dt$$
converges.  I'm not sure why you can't just use the standard argument of $\exp(i\omega t)$ averaging to zero as the limit of integration tends to zero? (which would simply give $G^{(0)}(\lambda,E)=1/(E-\epsilon_\lambda)$ instead of $G^{(0)}(\lambda,E)=1/(E-\epsilon_\lambda+i\delta)$
My understanding of the Green's function is that it gives the scattering amplitude.  The unperturbed case (to my understanding) is creating a particle in the state with quantum number $\lambda$, then measuring it a time $t$ later in the same state without the particle interacting with anything.  What does it mean to have an (essentially) infinite probability for the particle being in the state corresponding to $\epsilon_\lambda$?



Because that "physicist's argument" is, well, wrong.  Whenever your teacher invoked the argument, they secretly sneaked in the $i \delta$ without telling you.  Younger kids are sometimes allergic to mathematics, you know.

And that $i \delta$ is all-important for the causality structure, too.

Probability is not infinite.  The distribution is a delta function with infinite density at one point, and is integrated to the grand total of one.  The state never changes, as expected.

edit
In response to OP's follow up question.
Let's try inverse Fourier transform the thing:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{\omega - E + i \delta}
$$
This is to be evaluated using contour integral.  Clearly the integrand has only one pole in the upper half-plane at $\omega = E - i\delta$.
If $t < 0$, the $e^{i\omega\vert t \vert}$ factor forces us to close the contour from the lower half-plane, miss the pole, and get zero for the integral.  If $t > 0$, we close the contour from above, pick up the pole, and obtain $i e^{-i E t}$.
As a distribution (i.e. within an $\omega$ integral), we can legitimately identify
$$
\frac{1}{\omega - E + i\delta} \sim 2\pi i \, \Theta(t) \delta(\omega-E).
$$
The principal part $P\!\left(\frac{1}{\omega - E}\right)$ always integrates to zero.  And note that $\Theta(t)$: causality is built in!
edit 2
Wake up, see the answer I wrote last night, and realize there's some inaccuracy in the claim that you can identify the propagator with the $\delta$-function.  Not always; only within a free theory.
The $P\!\left(\frac{1}{\omega - E}\right)$ principal part does have an effect if the propagator is convolved with anything more complicated than $e^{-i\omega t}$.  But that happens only when the system isn't free.  So interaction is still necessary for scattering.

I was thinking about this, and I was just wondering for point 2 isn't the distribution slightly different from the delta function?  It seems that the distribution should be closer to $1/E$, which would have a non-zero distribution at other possible energies.  I get this even when using the Fourier transform of a step function, which gives $\pi\delta(E-\epsilon_\lambda)+\frac{1}{i(E-\epsilon_\lambda)}$.  This would seem to imply scattering right?
